# Adding a music to Apple Music Library using Apple Script

Tags: ios, applescript, javascript-automation, apple-music

I have an AppleScript, which `duplicates` the currentTrack to my AppleMusic `Library`. Although, it seems that the Library has a capacity of (length of the library + 1), and whenever I add a new track using the `duplicate` this capacity is not increased. This means, that whenever I try to add another track, it doesn't work. Although, if I remove any other item, then 1 capacity is freed, and I can add another track to my Library.

If I manually add another track to the Library using the Apple Music app, then the capacity is updated, and I can add another track using the AppleScript script.

```
tell application "Music"
    set currentTrack to current track
    duplicate currentTrack to source "Library"
end tell
```

Update: the snippet below seems to be working (it's JXA tho). The `duplicate` method is not returning the added track (just `true`), probably because it's an async operation. That's why the `delay`. Not sure if there's a better way to achieve the same, my knowledge of this is a bit limited.
Bonus: Changing the rating of the added item.

```
var music = Application("Music")
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

var track = music.currentTrack
track.loved = true

var myLib = music.sources['Library']
track.duplicate({ to: myLib })

delay(4)

myLib.tracks().find(t => t.name() === track.name() && t.artist() === track.artist()).rating = 100
```

Update 2:
The one above does not work if I `Create Station...`. It works as expected if I play any of the Playlists available in the *Browse* section. I'm starting to see a pattern here... it looks like I can only add to my `Library` the tracks that belong to a Playlist.
I've compared the properties of the same song when played using the `Create Station` and from another playlist. The only relevant difference is the IDs of both, their `databaseID` and `persistentId` are different. So my assumption is that this is the reason.

Update3: this [blog post](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/2011/11/some-itunes-match-applescripting-notes/) explains a lot the situation above.

Comment: What is your AppleScript looking like ?

Comment: I have added the code snippet. Although, for some reason, I was able to add a few songs. But this already happened, and it seems to work sometimes. And other times, it doesn't.

Comment: As far as I understand, the Music application's **duplicate** command does not physically write a new copy to the library folder on disk. It just creates a new link to the original, understandable to the application. Therefore, the size of the library does not increase. The equivalent of manually adding a song (that is, the equivalent of physically writing to disk) is the **add** command, not the **duplicate** command. And the **add** command adds only existing files of your file system as I  understand.

Comment: I've managed to get it working (magic?!), and it even syncs with the cloud, so there's an async operation before it's actually added.